# PHP - Subscribe to Group using Mailchimp API

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I followed Drewm/Mailchimp API to integrate may custom form into Mailchimp.

I successfully subscribed the users to my list. But when I include the Subscribe to Group line of codes, the whole function is not working, even the Subscribe to List is not working anymore.

But when I remove the Subscribe to Group, the Subscribe to List is working again.

Here is my code:

```
include 'MailChimp.php';

$MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp('ab4dc1be0f31933f5f8bcdc82231a47d-us4');
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
    'id'                => '0c043be204',
    'email'             => array('email'=>$email),
    'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=>$firstname, 'LNAME'=>$lastname),
    //                     'groupings' => array(
    //                         array( 
    //                             'id' => 19361, 
    //                             'groups' => array($_POST['group'])
    //                         ) 
    //                     )
    // ),
    'double_optin'      => false,
    'update_existing'   => true,
    'replace_interests' => false,
    'send_welcome'      => false,
));

print_r($result);
```

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Email Address</label><br>
    <input name="Email" type="email" required="required" id="Email" placeholder="Email">

    <label>First Name</label><br>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" required="required" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">

    <label>Last Name</label><br>
    <input name="LastName" type="text" required="required" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name">

    <div id="group">
    <label>Areas of Interest</label><br>
    <input name="group[]" type="checkbox" id="Interest1" class="interest"><label>Turf</label><br>
    <input name="group[]" type="checkbox" id="Interest2" class="interest"><label>Landcare</label><br>
    <input name="group[]" type="checkbox" id="Interest3" class="interest"><label>Landscaping</label><br>
    <input name="group[]" type="checkbox" id="Interest4" class="interest"><label>Landscaping Architects</label><br>
    <input name="group[]" type="checkbox" id="Interest5" class="interest"><label>Nurseries</label>
</div>
```

I don't know what I am missing or what is wrong with the code. Hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: What error are you receiving back from the API?

Comment: There is no error. It's just not doing what it is supposed to do. When I run the code above, it works fine. But when I remove the comment, delete the ")" on the "$lastname" then it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Like it doesn't subscribe the user at all? What is the actual body of the response you're getting back from MailChimp?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't subscribe the user when I include the commented code. And there's also no response from Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days I finally figured it out!! The code construct is correct, my fault is that I am using a wrong version of the API. Before, I didn't noticed that what I downloaded is the Mailchimp API 2.0+, but for my code above, I should be using the API 1.0+ version.